# Instagram - how to like multiple times the same media

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I'd like to implement an android app with a feature to obtain multiple likes on a media. I can get one like per `media_id` using a post request to `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/media_id/like/` but is there a way to like a `media_id` many times?

Answer (score 0):

You can only like once with a user's access_token (one user can only like a photo once)

Also it is against instagram policy to automate liking